# How do you programmatically retrieve step and order that an assessment question was defined in OmniScript?

Tags: api, metadata-api, omnistudio, omniscript

I want to be able to create an assessment summary but certain question and question responses need to be grouped together in order to create a logical summary document. Is there a way to retrieve them via a script or Apex?